# Html button is too small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html form with an add button which is attached to the right hand side of a textbox, and a separate delete button. The form uses some bootstrap css. However, the delete button shows up on the page as a small grey square, with no text inside it. What is making it show up so strangely?

```
<form id = "myform">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<h3> New Group: </h3>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id = "input" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick = "addTag()" >Add</button>
      </span>

    </div><!-- /input-group -->




<table class = "table" padding = "5">
<ul id = "list" class="list-group">


</ul>
</table>

<button type = "button" class="btn btn-default" value = "Delete" id = "deleteBtn" onClick = "if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
 Delete()"></button>

</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my button so tiny?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923362/why-is-my-button-so-tiny)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must move the text from `value` in between the tags

```
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-default" id = "deleteBtn" onClick = "if(confirm('Are you sure?')) Delete()">Delete</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3e3M/)

Answer (score 0):

The spaces. You shouldn't use spaces for and after your "="-s. So:

```
value = "Delete"
```

is bad.

```
value="Delete"
```

is okay. Good luck! :-)

Comment: AFAIK type = "button" will be interpreted as type="true" ""="true" ""="button", but I admit it needs a deeper crossbrowser testing.